# Use CrossHair to distinguish between automata and python function

Tags: python, solver, finite-automata, model-checking

I have a function which defines a language, let's call L, this function gets a word and returns True or False.

I have also a deterministic finite autumata which suppose to accept words that are in the language and regret words that are not in the language L.

My mission is to get a counterexample that will distinguish between the dfa and the python function.

I wonder if CrossHair can be useful for this task.

I expect for something like:

```
counterexmaple = checker(dfa, func)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

#### Summary

You may be able to use [CrossHair](https://github.com/pschanely/CrossHair) to solve this sort of problem. Executing a deterministic finite automata (DFA) is going to involve a lot of branch-y behavior, though, and CrossHair does not perform very well in this situation. In most cases, you may be better off using a randomized testing approach with [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/). I'll describe both approaches.

#### Preliminaries

First, you'll want to be able to express your DFA in python to compare the implementations. Here is an example:

```py
from typing import Tuple, Dict

# We construct a DFA that accepts any string that ends                                                                                                                        
# with "abc":                                                                                                                                                                 
_TRANSITION_TABLE: Dict[Tuple[int, str], int] = {
    # state #0: we have not yet seen "a" (initial state)                                                                                                                      
    (0, 'a'): 1,
    # state #1: we've seen "a"                                                                                                                                                
    (1, 'a'): 1,
    (1, 'b'): 2,
    # state #2: we've seen "ab"                                                                                                                                               
    (2, 'a'): 1,
    (2, 'c'): 3,
    # state #3: we've seen "abc" (final state)                                                                                                                                
    (3, 'a'): 1,
}

def dfa_checker(s: str) -> bool:
    state = 0
    for char in s:
        state = _TRANSITION_TABLE.get((state, char), 0)
    return state == 3

def correct_custom_checker(s: str) -> bool:
    return s.endswith("abc")

def incorrect_custom_checker(s: str) -> bool:
    return s.endswith("bc")
```

#### CrossHair Solution

You can give the custom implementation a contract declaring that its result is the same as the DFA:

```py
def incorrect_custom_checker(s: str) -> bool:
    ''' post: __return__ == dfa_checker(s) '''
    return bool(re.fullmatch('[abc]*', s) and s.endswith("bc"))
```

Though not required for the real function, adding a regular expression for our alphabet (abc) helps CrossHair find a solution. Now we can have CrossHair attempt to refute the contract:

```
$ crosshair check example.py
example.py:29:error:false when calling incorrect_custom_checker(s = 'bc') (which returns True)
```

And it finds the counterexample "bc" which is accepted by incorrect_custom_checker() but refused by the DFA.

Additionally, there is a very new, largely undocumented, crosshair command that makes this sort of thing even easier. You can compare any two arbitrary python functions using:

```
$ crosshair diffbehavior example.incorrect_custom_checker example.dfa_checker
  given: (s='bc')
- returns: True
+ returns: False
```

If you need to do this fully programmatically, you could reach into the CrossHair internals that do this [here](https://github.com/pschanely/CrossHair/blob/2a124c7d599c42c95aeb66437ad6e3e62e45b8c1/crosshair/behavior_diff.py#L65). This approach will break as the CrossHair codebase evolves, but I've included it here for completeness.

#### Hypothesis Solution

As I was alluding to earlier, doing lots of randomized testing is likely to work better for you. Here is a way to do this in hypothesis:

```py
import hypothesis
from hypothesis.strategies import text
@hypothesis.given(text(alphabet="abc"))
def test_checkers_equivalent(s: str) -> None:
    assert dfa_checker(s) == incorrect_custom_checker(s)
```

Running `pytest example.py` will find the same "bc" counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer,
According to the Hypothesis Solution, is there a way to run it not as a test but with standard running of the project?

Comment: Sadly, I don't know of a way to run hypothesis inline. Might be appropriate as another stack overflow question? The hypothesis community is pretty active and friendly.

Comment: according to what you wrote "If you need to do this fully programmatically, you could reach into the CrossHair internals that do this here" 
I wonder if it's possible to add the  "pre:" option to AnalysisOptions
Thanks